# How to decrypt hash sha 256 encrypted strings without knowing the key?

Tags: string, encryption, cryptography, sha256, sha

for a private research project I wonder if its possible to decrypt SHA256 encrypted strings without having the key and just have Examples of encrypted and decrypted strings.

As an example, I have 1000 Strings as decrypted text and I have the 1000 Strings encrypted. Can't this information be used to decrypt those strings?

I just want to give notice, that I totally do not have any clue about cryptographie and I am sorry if my questions sounds to newbie.

Best regards,
Heini

Comment: Sha256 is a one-way-hash - not encryption. One-way-hash's are per design created so you can not get back to the original value that went into the hash.

Comment: If the hashed strings are very short like passwords you can try to brute force them or use a rainbow table to get the original text from SHA256 hash. But that will not work for all values, depending on the length and the used characters may be for some of your values and it may take some weeks of computation.

Answer (score 2):

> As an example, I have 1000 Strings as [original] text and I have the 1000 Strings [hash]. Can't this information be used to [identify] those strings?

Sure.  Hash each string, and write down "this string went to that hash", or, write it the other direction so you can look up a possible original string from a hash value.  You've just created a small [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

> I wonder if its possible to decrypt SHA256 encrypted strings without having the key

SHA-256 is a digest algorithm, not an encryption algorithm (as [Ebbe M. Pedersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196561/ebbe-m-pedersen) pointed out in a comment).  Digest algorithms don't have keys, and are designed to not be reversible (and even though no collisions are currently known for SHA-256, they're guaranteed to exist by the pigeon-hole principle... so there's no one right answer).

Protocols/processes/algorithms utilizing digest algorithms will often add a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) when hashing, but that's different than a key.  The purpose of the salt is to 'defeat' rainbow tables... since you need a new table for every different salt.